# Error creating bean with name 'as' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have a Account Business Service which in which i am coding my Business Requirements. And for that Business Service i have a Advice class of SecurityCheck

```java
package com.jlcindia.spring.bservices;

public class AccountService {
    public void getBal() {
        System.out.println("Get bal is successfull");
    }
    public void myDeposit() {
        System.out.println("MY Deposit is successfull");
    }
    public void myWithdraw() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("WIthdraw begin");
        int i=0;
        if (i == 1){
            throw new InSufficientFundsException();
        }
        System.out.println("WIthdraw end");
    }

}
```

The advice class is as follows:

```java
package com.jlcindia.spring.mservices;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class SecurityService {

    @Pointcut(value="execution(* com.jlcindia.spring.bservices.AccountService.my*(..))")
    public void pc1(){}
    @Pointcut(value="execution(* com.jlcindia.spring.bservices.CustomerService.del*(..))")
    public void pc2(){}

    @Around("pc1() or pc2()")
    public void verifyUser(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("SS-verifyUser()-Begin");
        pjp.proceed();
        System.out.println("SS-verifyUser()-END");
    }
}
```

I use *annotation-config.xml* file to configure the Business Service and Advice class as follows:

```xml
<bean id="as" class="com.jlcindia.spring.bservices.AccountService" />
<bean id="security" class="com.jlcindia.spring.mservices.SecurityService"/>
```

Here is the code to test it:

```java
package com.jlcindia.spring.aop;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.jlcindia.spring.bservices.AccountService;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        AccountService ast = (AccountService)ctx.getBean("as");
        ast.myDeposit();
        ast.getBal();
        try{
            ast.myWithdraw();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("***sorry****");
        }
    }
}
```

When I am running my client code to test the services whether the advice is applying or not I am getting this exception;

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'as' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut pc1
```

The full stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'as' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut pc1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.jlcindia.spring.aop.Client.main(Client.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut pc1
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:316)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:195)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:181)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:162)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:200)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:254)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:286)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 11 more</h3>
```

Please help to figure out why this error occuring while creating the bean 'as'(AccountService). I don't have much knowledge on AOP, i am learner now... so please i need a little help on this question. thank you for your patience to read this...

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your pointcut. Please change

```
@Around("pc1() or pc2()")
```

to

```
@Around("pc1() || pc2()")
```

*P.S.: And please use less chaotic source code and prose text formatting next time, it took me 5+ minutes to edit your question in order to make it more readable for myself and others.*